# Using SQL query to determine if a table exists

Tags: sql, oracle

Guys is there any other way to determine a  table exists other than below

1. `select count(*) from <table> where rownum =1`
2. `select * from user_table where table_name=<table>`

kindly let me know the best way to check whether a table exists using oracle sql.

Thanks for the answer , my requirement is to check from the first date of current month ie 01/12/2010  with table name in the format suresh_20101201 exists in the database, if not then it should check for table suresh_20101202 and thereon till suresh_20101231 . is it possible to do in oracle sql query.

Comment: I hope you're not responsible for a db design that calls for multiple tables with a date in their name ;) Does each table have a different structure?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do this (in oracle, in mssql there is a bit different):

```
select count(*)
from all_objects
where object_type in ('TABLE','VIEW')
and object_name = 'your_table_name';
```

Comment: +1 because he asked for Oracle. Also, the object_name must be upper-cased.

Comment: @Thilo: no, object names in Oracle don't have to be uppercase. They usually are, but they don't have to be.

Comment: They almost always are. And unless you created a table with the name in quotes (to make it case-sensitive), ALL_OBJECTS will have the table name uppercased.

Answer (score 1):

In most sql servers there is a system domain where you can query for a table's existence.  It's highly implementation specific though.  For example, in recent versions of [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html):

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
  AND table_name LIKE 'whatever'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask your server's system catalog. Not sure what database you meant but for SQL Server it would be:

```
select * from sys.tables where name='your-table-name-'
```

Answer (score 1):

Used this in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' AND OWNER = 'myschema' AND OBJECT_NAME = 'your_table_name')
```

This will return either a `0` or `1` if your table exists or not in the `ALL_OBJECTS` records.

Answer (score 1):

Below query can be triggered to Oracle for checking whether any Table present in DB or not:

```
SELECT count(*) count FROM dba_tables where table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

Above query will return count 1 if table 'TABLE_NAME' is present in Database

Answer (score -1):

Look in the schema,  might event be able to use sys.objects and check for a type at the same time.....

Something like