# Java code to check if a given User, Schema, Table exists?

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I want to make Java code (using Oracle 11g and JDBC also) which will check if a particular User or Schema exists or not. How can I do this by using only Java code and not by executing SQL queries (inside my java code) to do the checking ?

Thanks.

EDIT -

METHOD 1:

In MySQL, we can use something like this -

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
DatabaseMetaData DMD = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet res = DMD.getCatalogs();
 while (res.next()) {
      String database = res.getString("TABLE_CAT");
}
```

Now put an if inside the while to check it given DB exists.

METHOD 2:

OR, you can execute some queries like mentioned in this post.
[Using SQL query to determine if a table exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385346/using-sql-query-to-determine-if-a-table-exists)

I want to use something like method 1 to do the job instead of method 2 - That is what i meant.

Comment: Without querying database, how would you know what you have on database? I see only option is, keep another copy of those entries in flat file inside your app (which is very bad way in my opinion).

Comment: You can try to establish the connection without executing query. But this will work only if db user has `connect` authority.

Comment: @gkuzmin: Is establishing connection enough to get schema and user details? Don't get me wrong, I am not expert on DB side.

Comment: for tables : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927807/how-can-i-detect-a-sql-tables-existence-in-java

Comment: **Why** is it that you don't want to run any queries against the database?  This seems like a bizarre restriction to have when you want to get data from the database.  Additionally depending on the reason it may also rule out approaches like `conn.getMetaData()` (which of course runs SQL queries behind the scenes to get its data).

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle - I understand that the Java code must be running queries behind the scenes to find a database. But using a simple method instead of putting many queries in code makes the code neat and smaller.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle -
Maybe we can create our own method which executes SQL statements to check if a user exists and then use this method in any code which needs to do such a job. 
That raises another question - will our method be as good as the code that executes SQL behind the scenes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pure JDBC way to interrogate the database about this sort of thing is to use the [DatabaseMetaData class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) in your Java application.  [DatabaseMetaData.getSchemas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getSchemas%28%29) will give you the set of schemas in the database.  [DatabaseMetaData.getTables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) will give you a listing of the tables.  You can write code that iterates through these `ResultSet` objects to see if a particular table or schema exists.

Of course, behind the scenes, the JDBC driver is simply executing SQL queries against the Oracle data dictionary to get this information.

Comment: Maybe we can create our own method which executes SQL statements to check if a user exists and then use this method in any code which needs to do such a job. 
That raises another question - will our method be as good as the code that executes SQL behind the scenes ?

Comment: @sweetdreams - Of course, you could write your own code.  If you're comfortable using the `DatabaseMetaData` class, though, there probably isn't much benefit to writing custom SQL.  If you want to get a subset of the data one of the predefined methods returns (i.e. you want to get a single row rather than iterating through hundreds of rows to determine if a particular user exists), you may be able to write a more efficient query than the folks that wrote the JDBC driver developed.  It is unlikely, though, that you'd write a more efficient query in general.